# different sql query every 24 hours in php script

Tags: php, mysql, timer

I have this php script that displays an sql table in a html webpage. Here is the code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Your Page Title</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$database="Batabase_xxx";
mysql_connect ("localhost", "User_xxx", "password_xxx");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT id,name,address,phone,hours FROM table_xxx" )
or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
print "found $num_rows results.<P>";
print "<table width=250 border=1>\n";
while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
print "<tr>\n";
foreach ($get_info as $field)
print "\t<td><font face=arial size=2/>$field</font></td>\n";
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that i now have 23 different tables and I would like to select a different one each day.
*For example:* Today I want to select table_1, tommorow table_2 etc. When I reach table_23(the last table) I want to reset and start all over again from table_1.
Is that possible?(I want to avoid to merge 23 tables into 1)
Please note that i m totally new to this and every help is appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with storing this in a database table for config values, since it's easy to setup and you can easily add more settings later for other things.

Here's an example. First create the table holding configuration values:

```
CREATE TABLE config_values (
  id int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  key_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  value varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then you insert an entry for this:

```
INSERT INTO config_values(key_name, value) VALUES ('day_counter', 1);
```

Then before you execute your script, you see what day it is, and use in in the table name

```
$current_day_query = mysql_query(
    "SELECT value FROM config_values WHERE key_name = 'day_counter'"
);
$current_day_result = mysql_fetch_row($current_day_query);
$current_day = reset($current_day_result);
$table_name = 'table_' . $current_day;

// code
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT id,name,address,phone,hours FROM $table_name" )
// more code
```

And last, don't forget to increment/reset the counter before you finish:

```
if ($current_day == 23) {
    $next_day = 0;
}
else {
    $next_day = $current_day + 1;
}
$increment_query = mysql_query(
    "UPDATE config_values SET value = $next_day WHERE key_name = 'day_counter'"
);
```

Comment: I think this is going to change the day every time i execute the script. Am i wrong? I need it to change table every day

Comment: Indeed, it will. I thought you was going to use it only once a day via cron job. Anyway, it's a simple matter to check if the script has been run that day. Just add another config value holding the date of last script run, and check it before incrementing the day counter.
For example, you run it today. The counter goes from 1 to 2. Then you run it tomorrow morning. It goes from 2 to 3, but let's say you run it again tomorrow evening. You can check if {today's date} == {the 2nd database config value holding the day of the last run}. If it doesn't, you increment, if it does - do nothing.

Comment: Cheers! It worked :). Just to note 2 mistakes : `$current_day_result = mysql_fetch_row($current_day_result);` was giving NULL and I changed it to `$current_day_result = mysql_fetch_row($current_day_query);` . also `$next_day = 0` was missing an `;` . Anyway Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Your Page Title</title></head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['daynumber']) && $_COOKIE['daynumber']!=NULL)
{
if($_COOKIE['daynumber']!=23) { $_COOKIE['daynumber'] += 1; }
}
else
{
  $_COOKIE['daynumber'] = 1;
}
$database="Batabase_xxx";
mysql_connect ("localhost", "User_xxx", "password_xxx");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT id,name,address,phone,hours FROM table_".$_COOKIE['daynumber'])
or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
print "found $num_rows results.<P>";
print "<table width=250 border=1>\n";
while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
print "<tr>\n";
foreach ($get_info as $field)
print "\t<td><font face=arial size=2/>$field</font></td>\n";
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There was some typo mistake. I have corrected it now.